# Data dictionary object check with rs_dd_check

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

rs_dd_check is a great function to check ddic objects. But the function module does not fit me that i can call it directly because i need to use it on older systems which only have the dialog and you can not export the messages out of the fm.

so i extracted some code out of it (out of perform check_object subroutine) which should be sufficient, and it is, for tables and structures it works!!! But for every other element it's not working. :(

Basically im creating a log and then doing check and then importing from memory id 'CHE' for example CHETABLSFLIGHT into variable/table lt_log

Im sure that for other elements it is creating logs but im not sure if it fill them up...Because lt_log stays empty.

```
report report name.

    data:  objname type rsedd0-ddobjname value 'object_name', eg sflighs
           eutype  type rsdxx-eutype value 'object_type', eg T 
           enqtype type rsdeo-objtype,
           protid  type sy-tabix,
           titletxt TYPE sprot_i-prot,
           actmode TYPE ddrefstruc-mode VALUE 9,
           act_res type STANDARD TABLE OF dctablres,
           lt_log type STANDARD TABLE OF trlogm .






*TRANSLATE T INTO TABL ETC
    call function 'INTERN_TRANSL_EUTYPE' "Sperrtyp
      exporting
        eutype       = eutype
      importing
        enqueue_type = enqtype.

*CREATING LOG?
    call function 'DD_OBJ_PROT_OPEN'
      exporting
        objectname = objname
        objecttype = enqtype
        level      = 1
        device     = 'M'  "Memory with report RSPUTPRT as frontend
        ddfunc     = 'CHE'
      importing
        prid       = protid
      exceptions
        others     = 01.



*CHECKING SYNTAX
    case eutype .

      when 'T'.
        titletxt = 'CHECKING TABLES'.
        call function 'DD_TABL_ACT'
          exporting
            device      = 'M'
            path        = ' '
            tabname     = objname
            timer_on    = ' '
            prid        = protid
            act_mode    = actmode
            protname    = ''
          tables
            act_res_tab = act_res
          exceptions
            others      = 03.    "Abbruch -> Protokoll anzeigen

         when 'V'.                        "View
          titletxt = 'CHECKING VIEWS'.
          call function 'DD_VIEW_ACT'
            exporting
              viewname  = objname
              get_state = 'M'
              act_mode  = actmode
              prid      = protid
              protname  = ''
            exceptions
              others    = 03.


      when others.
    endcase.


TRANSLATE OBJNAME USING '/-\-'.
data lv_mem_id(200) type c.
CONCATENATE 'CHE' enqtype objname into lv_mem_id. "EX CHETABLTABLE_NAME
IMPORT lt_log FROM MEMORY ID lv_mem_id.
```

Comment: ...so what is the actual problem?

Comment: import retrieves empty array (lt_log).(The last line of my code) It returns values only when tables and structures are checked.

Comment: do `objname` and `enqtype` variables filled?